# Enabling Regex/CLR Capabilities with SQL Server Docker Compose

Tags: sql-server, regex, macos, docker, docker-compose

I have created a SQL Server 2017 Docker container with Mac OS using Docker compose, and am parsing very large tables I have been importing into a database from .txt files but I am finding that some of the data I am parsing may be parsed easier with more robust Regex features than what I can utilize with standard SQL Server 2017.

I am wondering if:

1. It is possible to implement a CLR/Regex solution into a Docker container using compose?
2. If possible, how would this be set up with Docker/compose?
3. Is there a Microsoft approved way of doing this that I have overlooked and wasted every one’s time by posting this? If so, I apologize but appreciate being pointed in the right direction if this is the case!

Thank you

Comment: If the operations are Regex heavy but not update / join heavy then yes this is most likely better achieved external to SQL Server. My first step would be using Powrshell but I don't know exacly what you are doing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am looking to extract similar patterns at varying positions in nvarchar fields. The patterns are similar but not consistent all the time. I am dealing with a table that has more than 5 million records. Have you used a Dockerized version of SQL server with Powershell?

Comment: No I haven't but I guess you add something like this https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell to include it in your docker image, then you should be able to include your powershell scripts. But for a file that large I think you're going to probably have to go more specialised. This link https://superuser.com/questions/844844/how-to-apply-regex-to-large-text-file suggests using `GREP` or `SED`. You just have to find a sufficiently fast way to do what you want, then include that stuff in the docker.

Comment: There's also some info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255373/replace-text-quickly-in-very-large-file other solutions might be some compiled custom .Net or Java code or Python or Perl. I only have a little experience with .Net. Any reason it needs to be inside docker - whats the objective here?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I will look at those links. I am using Docker because I am working alongside someone that uses SQL server in a Windows environment while I am using a Mac. So we split up the work between our two machines. Not ideal for sure but just the cards we are dealt currently. I’m just wondering if someone else has done something similar with Docker, SQL Server & Regex Integration.

Comment: One option would be that you could share an Azure SQL then you can both connect and share data and scale it up when you need to.

Comment: In fact depending on your requirements, a datalake approach might be better. If you're doing a lot of text operations and not a lot of relational stuff (joining, grouping, aggregating on a row basis) then datalake + databricks may suit you better. Again these are cloud resources that you can share between you and are easy to provision. You can get your self a free Azure account to experiment.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Awesome. Thank you for the suggestions. I will look into them. If I could just focus on a solution outside of SQL Server I know I would not have as much to think about or to work around. I appreciate your time and feedback!

Comment: I was looking for a basic databricks tutorial involving regex for you but coulddn't find one, just to give you an idea.